# remove specific rules out of inline CSS

Tags: css, regex

i'd like to remove some specific css rules (i.e. width and height) out of inline style attributes.

so i want to transform the following:

```
<table id="foo" style="border:1px #000 solid; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
```

into

```
<table id="foo" style="border:1px #000 solid">
```

is there a handy regex that solves my problem?

thank you all in advance

Comment: `s/; width: 100px; height: 100px;//g`. Seriously, why don't you just read the regex docs of your language? Regular expressions aren't some kind of fairy dust you sprenkle on your code to make it "magical". (Hm, I said quite the same about jQuery a little while ago.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this (tested in Vim and Ruby):

```
/(width|height):\s*\d+(px|%);?//
```

Of course you should use your editor's (or language's) syntax for regexps (for example in Vim you have to prepend backslash before '(','|',')' and '+'

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific, but how about `/[\s;"']width: .+;/`. You need to feed that to a replace function or something, but I can't help you there because I don't know what language you're in.

Comment: thanks, but that would only find the width rule. i want to remove it from the <table>-tag so that only the other rules remain in the style-attribute

Comment: You will probably need some kind of boundary check in the beginning of the pattern. Otherwise a pattern to remove `height` rules will mess up `line-height` rules bad...

Comment: Expanded the answer in response to above comments

Answer (score 0):

No, you generally cannot do all that in a regular expression, because HTML is not a regular language.

Use an HTML parser to get at the `style` attribute from `table` tags, then use the regular expressions `width:.+?(;|$)` and `height:.+?(;|$)`.

Comment: `<nitpicking>`if width is the last item, it need not end with a semicolon, right?`</nitpicking>`

Comment: Fixed.  (comments need at least 15 characters)

Answer (score 0):

Enable regex search in your editor and try:

```
width="[^"]*"
height="[^"]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware: regular expressions cannot correctly parse HTML.

Use a parser instead.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::Parser;

die "Usage: $0 html-file\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

sub start {
  my($tag,$attr,$attrseq,$text,$skipped) = @_;

  print $skipped;
  unless ($attr->{style} && $attr->{style} =~ /width|height/) {
    print $text;
    return;
  }

  my %style = $attr->{style} =~ /
    \s*      # optional leading space
    (.+?) :  # property, e.g., width
    \s*      # optional separating space
    ([^;]+)  # value, e.g., 100px
    ;?       # optional separator
  /gx;

  delete @style{qw/ width height /};
  $attr->{style} = join "; " =>
                   map "$_: $style{$_}",
                   keys %style;

  print "<$tag ",
          join(" " => map qq[$_="$attr->{$_}"], @$attrseq),
        ">";
}

my $p = HTML::Parser->new(
  api_version => 3,
  marked_sections => 1,
  start_h => [ \&start => "tag, attr, attrseq, text, skipped_text" ],
  end_h => [ sub { print @_ } => "skipped_text, text" ],
);

undef $/;
$p->parse(<>);
```